# Android unknown logcat messages V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logcat

I am getting a lot of following logs in my android studio logcat, anyone knows what are these?

```
2020-12-16 11:46:18.717 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
2020-12-16 11:46:19.022 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
2020-12-16 11:46:19.322 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
2020-12-16 11:46:19.727 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
2020-12-16 11:46:19.929 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
2020-12-16 11:46:20.230 14316-14485/com.livnao.androidsdk.sample V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 14316.
```

Comment: I experience this on occasion too. When it happens, the app in question runs much slower than normal. I only noticed after upgrading my Pixel to Android 11.

Comment: @PPartisan did u figure out the cause?

Comment: I haven't, sorry. I tend to kill ADB when I see the problem, but it isn't always reliable.

Answer (score 8):

This is related to the *Database Inspector*. I opened it to check the database created and then the log lines started to appear. After stopping the inspector (in the tab, click the mobile name and you can select a menu called *Stop Inspector*), the log lines disappeared.

Comment: Yes as mentioned it does start only when I start the Database Inspector. But it is not stopping after selecting "Stop Inspector". It doesn't stop unless I relaunch the app either by killing it from the recent apps or re-running it from the Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check which process is causing this first with PID 14316.
After getting that you may get more information about these logs.

Comment: Its the sample app that I am running